# SharedPreferences sync

Tags: android, google-app-engine, sharedpreferences, google-cloud-storage, android-syncadapter

I desire the application state synchronized across the various devices that Users own phone and tablet. I want a way to automatically, or by a button for example, synchronize Android application settings (int and strings saved on SharedPreferences) with a Google account or APIs or automatic sync (in Google account Settings) but i'm very confused..

I see App Engine, GCM and "cloudendpoints"

So..what is the best solution to automatically sync the Preferences? Any example or guide? I think that the solution is easy but hard to find!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not easy.  AppEngine can handle the web server part easily in many ways.  The Android side will be harder, most particularly making it automatic.  Android probably stops preferences being changed arbitrarily by external data to avoid security vulnerabilities.

Approach the problem from the Android end by first updating your preferences with your own App, then try it from your own Service, and then add AppEngine client software to your service.  You will discover what you need to know along the way.

Comment: I know... Infact i'd like to use this library..see that https://code.google.com/p/cloudendpoints-sharedpreferences-sync/